BlenderBIM (Bonsai) sloped wall
I am wondering if it's possible to have a wall elevated on one side?
Left (1) is a IFC wall made with BlenderBIM and on the right (2) a Blender cube with the form I want to achieve.
I know it is possible with a slab but in this case it has to be a wall.


This question is about a third-party addon, which has its own separate documentation here, and its own separate help community here. This question is not about Blender itself.

@TheLabCat Questions about third party addons have been considered on topic as outlined on https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/ and https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3043 , though a case could be made for Bonsai. Since it is a considerably different workflow and scope running on top of Blender we may or may not want it here. I'd be inclined to accept questions about it, but I might be biased by my personal interest. We could open an interesting topic specifically about Bonsai on Meta to see what the community thinks if questions about it are controversial.

Thank you both I will keep it in mind next time!

I agree with Duarte, although I'm also biased since it's also my field of expertise and I participate in the Osarch community. Usually I redirect people to the OsArch channels but stackexchange has a really specific way to operate thats makes it way more efficient than parsing messages on regular forums, or reading some documentation.  Bonsai tends to attract tool-oriented people that will increase the value of this site's database in the long run. My 2 cents.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos understood. I read through the questions, and I don’t think your bias has unfairly influenced your decision. Will keep them in mind for next time. Thanks!


Activate the BIM Wall tool
Add a wall
From the properties sidebar, under the Tool tab, press Add a Void
A new blue colored cube void will be added. Adjust its position as desired
Press Tab to enter edit mode.
Select the top vertex and adjust the position to make a slope as desired
Duplicate the top vertex and move them above if you desire a parallel slope on top
Press E to extrude them and create another body for the top slope. Make sure it covers the whole wall
Press Tab to exit Edit Mode
Select the void and then ⇧ Shift-select the wall by this order
Go to the Properties Window > Scene and under the  Geometry and Materials tab (the sphere icon) expand the Geometric Relationships > Voids panel
Press Add Opening


Alternatively, see Gorgeous's method, for a lighter weight solution that uses simple planes for bisecting the wall.

Amazing! That was precisely what I was looking for, thanks a lot for the detailed and to the point answer!

You can also use half plane clip objects which are a feature that are more obscure than regular voids in the IFC schema. Instead of using geometry to clip other geometry (think a boolean operation in Blender), here we use a plane and a direction (or normal) to slice some geometry.
1- Build a wall

2- Add a vanilla Blender plane object that will act as the slope. Duplicate it and move it along its local Z axis. Rotate the lower plane 180° along its Y or X axis to make it face downward.

3- Select one of the planes, then ⇧ Shift +  Left Click on the wall to select and activate it. Go into the Geometry and Materials tab, then expand the Booleans subpanel from the Geometry Relationships panel. Click on the + button. The wall is cut by the half plane clip solid.


4- Repeat with the other plane (I slightly modified the plane positions in the next image to better represent your goal)

Note this can also be achieved with a Boolean modifier in Blender set to exact mode and a plane object (or any planar geometry, see this reference). The geometry does need to cover the entirety of the bounding box of the cut object. Note this paragraph is not directly related to the answer but provides some background as to what happens and the difference with the other answer.


Ah I already wondered if it was also possible in such a way since I saw the boolean tab because of Duarte's answer. This is just as useful thank you! You guys are hero's :)

Nice, was wondering how to do this. Seems like a "cleaner" solution, than mucking about with that arbitrary boolean geometry

Yeah I prefer it, feels cleaner and less bloaty, and it doesn't break if you change the height of your wall since it's clipping evrything above the plane. But the UI / UX is not great at the moment unfortunately, it's a pretty niche and hidden feature.

From my limited understanding, this is actually what is used under the hood when you use the mittre and butt, when you extend walls to other walls, but I could not figure out how to do one from scratch
